# Kohana v3 ORM Select and Where clause based on different table

Tags: mysql, orm, foreign-keys, kohana, relationship

Hi I need to do something like this:

$hours->task->job->where('group_id' , '=' , $num)->find_all();

This would return job information. Is there any way to tell orm to return the information from the $hours table instead?

Comment: your question is not clear enough.

Comment: I think he wants to return hour records based on a job's group_id.  Something like $hours->where('task->job->group_id, '=', $group_id)->find_all() but of course that won't work.

Comment: Yes Gerry's got it. I want something like that but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your basic PHP is wrong.

Also, make sure the plurality is accurate in the chaining:

$task->jobs assumes that task has a one to many relationship with jobs.  You can't use find_all unless it does.

That would be defined in your Model.

Try:

```
$task = ORM::factory( 'task' , $some_task_id );

$hours = $task->jobs->where( 'group_id', '=', $num )->find_all();
```

This assumes that the 'group_id' value is a column in the job Model.

Hope this helps a little. Add comments if you need more help.

Comment: This would still return the jobs table. I want a return of the tasks table. I think the best way to do it is with a join.